# How to find the angle between a vector and a plane?

Tags: physics

I have been given a Vector in $R^3$ , that hits the XY plane, and I have been given the refractive index for $Z>0  \text{and } Z<0$ , I want to find the angle this incident ray makes with the plane so that I can find the angle of refraction. How to do this?

Edit:- idea, as I'm trying to find the angle made with the XY plane, do I just need to solve the problem, using the x and y components?

Comment: If that vector has a length $> 0$, then it belongs to only one line... now it would be easy to solve the problem, isn't it?

Comment: I don't get you, I'm trying to find the angle that a given vector makes with the normal of the $X-y$ plane, how does the length help

Comment: Do you recall how the dot product between vectors relates to the angle between them?

Comment: A vector whose modulus is null, has infinitely many (half) lines incorporating it.

Comment: @Plutoro, $cos(\theta)= \frac{a*b}(ab}$

Comment: oh yeah thanks!

Comment: @Marco, got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway, this brief video explains very clearly how to find $\cos \theta$ (then it is just a matter of taking the arccos of $\theta$): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98C7iv8OcnI&t=30s.